# libqxt installation problem - features.path warning

Tags: qt, compilation, qt-creator, qmake, libqxt

I use Qt SDK 1.1.1 (everything installed exept experimental category) on Windows 7 and I'm trying to set up libqxt libaries for this enviroment. I downloaded and unpacked libqxt tip and ran configure.bat file using Qt for Desktop command line with -static -debug_and_release properties as administrator.

```
Testing for qmake...
Testing for mingw32-make...Using mingw32-make.
Testing for optional external libraries.
If tests fail, some features will not be available.
Testing for Berkeley DB...
   Berkeley DB disabled.
Testing for Zero Conf...
   Zero Conf disabled.
Configuration successful.
Generating makefiles...
WARNING: c:\QtSDK\Desktop\Qt\4.7.1\mingw\mkspecs\default\qmake.conf:108: Unescap
ed backslashes are deprecated.
WARNING: features.path is not defined: install target not created
Makefiles generated. Run mingw32-make now.
```

And so mingw32-make command do nothing... What should I do to compile it properly. I tried to use diffrent parameters but nothing changes...

Answer (score 0):

Run

> mingw32-make -f Makefile

After it completes then run

> mingw32-make -f Makefile install

This should install the Qxt library in C:\Qxt.

I have reached this far but the QXT widgets are not showing up in QT creator.